# Dataframe groupby condition with used column in groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I want to use "group by" by two columns A, B. A column is categorical variable and B column's type is 'datetime64[ns]'. Value column C is float type.
I want to get a result of summarized value C but only Cs that groupbefore the date of column B.

Is there any ways to solve this problem with using aggregation or applying lambda method?
Merging or joining the dataset with condition of "column B(dataset) >= column B(copied dataset)" can be one of a solution, however in my case dataset becomes too large.

Help ;-)

=example dataset=

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| category1 | 2022-01-02 | 1.0 |
| category1 | 2022-03-04 | 2.0 |
| category1 | 2022-07-10 | 3.0 |
| category1 | 2022-08-15 | 4.0 |
| category2 | 2022-03-04 | 5.0 |
| category2 | 2022-07-10 | 6.0 |

=expected result=

| Column A | Column B | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| category1 | 2022-01-02 | 1.0 |
| category1 | 2022-03-04 | 3.0 |
| category1 | 2022-07-10 | 6.0 |
| category1 | 2022-08-15 | 10.0 |
| category2 | 2022-03-04 | 5.0 |
| category2 | 2022-07-10 | 11.0 |

Comment: Do you need to use `group_by`? From the example given it would seem you only need `cumsum`. Do you have a more extensive example?

Comment: I didn't know there is function like cumsum in numpy module. Thank you! But I need to use group_by function. Cause I wrote here simple example, in fact there is one more column that I need to consider in grouping. It is categorical variable. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate cumulative sum of `Column C` for each group of `Column A`:

```
df['Result'] = df.groupby('Column A', sort=False)['Column C'].cumsum()
df.drop(columns='Column C', inplace=True)
```

---

```
     Column A     Column B  Result
0  category1   2022-01-02      1.0
1  category1   2022-03-04      3.0
2  category1   2022-07-10      6.0
3  category1   2022-08-15     10.0
4  category2   2022-03-04      5.0
5  category2   2022-07-10     11.0
```